# What is the difference between poi and poi-ooxml

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I'm learning about data driven testing using Selenium and Excel. I'm taking an online course that has asked used to add the Apache poi and poi-ooxml dependencies in Maven.

I'm struggling to understand what the differences between the two are. Are both required in order to retrieve data in Excel and pass these to our tests?

Thanks

Comment: Does [the Apache POI website explanation](http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components) not cover you?

Comment: I have already looked at that. It's still not clear what the difference is between the two JARs, hence my question.

Comment: Which file format do you want to work with? It lists all of the formats and which jars you need for which....

Comment: So the reason why the instructor has imported the two jars is due to working with different Excel formats? This is why I am confused. The instructor only uses .xlsx files, so my confusion stems from whether there was a need or a dependency to have both jars for any other reason.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Excel files has long history

- Excel 97-2003 workbook:

  This is a legacy Excel file that follows a binary file format. The file extension of the format is .xls.
  Excel 97-2003 in terms of apache poi is called - Horrible Spreadsheet Format  As the Excel file format is complex and contains a number of tricky characteristics,
  apache-poi jar has code to handle these file

[image]

- Excel 2007+ workbook:

  This is the default XML-based file format for Excel 2007 and later versions. It follows the Office Open XML (OOXML) format, which is a zipped, XML-based file format developed by Microsoft for representing office documents. The file extension of the format is .xlsx. ( DOCX,PPTX are other OOXML based examples).
  Excel 2007+ workbook in terms of apache poi is called - XML Spreadsheet Format -these file format are advanced version of HSSF and has additional features, code to handle these files are written in apache-poi-ooxml jar

[image]

- More reading

As .xls is almost dead but still some applications use it, so for backward compatibility both dependencies are required.
here is what Apache have to say -

- HSSF Excel XLS   poi For HSSF only, if common SS is needed see below
- Common SS    Excel XLS and XLSX  poi-ooxml   WorkbookFactory and friends
  all require poi-ooxml, not just core poi

you can read more at their official website http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components

Comment: Thank you vh1ne. That was very clearly explained and made total sense.

Comment: As of POI 4.1.2, `poi-ooxml` has a dependency on `poi`. So, is it still necessary to explicitly depend of both of them for backward compatibility?

Comment: @SayakMukhopadhyay - It's not because of backward compatibility, it's because of common base classes/interfaces and other shared classes, which reside in the poi artifact.

Comment: @kiwiwings So I believe that depending on `poi` is not really needed if I am depending on `poi-ooxml` since `poi-ooxml` is already depending on `poi`. I guess if I am using an API which only exists in `poi` I should depend on it as a best practice.

Comment: @SayakMukhopadhyay ok, I've got your comment wrong - you don't need to explicitly import the poi (main) artifact, as you pointed out, the maven dependency takes care of that. But when not using maven as a dependency mechanism, you need to have both on the class-/modulepath.